# passing function to .on giving error

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have image slider code which was not working on android tablet . but after adding following line it started working on android also.

```
$('#myImageFlow ').on("click touchstart",".sliderImage",touchStart());
function touchStart(event){
  };
```

but this is giving **Error::**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object .sliderImage has no method 'apply',
```

touchstart() i don't need but , instead of that if i am giving false then my slider is not working on android.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass function reference as the callback, not the value returned by the `touchStart` method.

```
$('#myImageFlow ').on("click touchstart", ".sliderImage", touchStart);
function touchStart(event){
};
```

Comment: touchstart()if  i write it as method then only slider working on android tablet